# My script of Datatable is not properly working (Not showing the entries show in one page and search field and multiple page options)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (Module:985)
>       at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
>       at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
>       at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

My script order are:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

There is no problem but

As you see here the _layout.cshtml Scripts are as following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/bootstrap.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Because you have not included the correct scripts and/or they are not in the correct order.

Comment: @StephenMuecke
oreder of scripts are: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dataTables-example').DataTable();
        });
    </script>

Comment: Edit your question (not in comments)!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you see it??

Comment: Looks fine. Are you sure you scripts are being loaded correctly, and that you do not have any duplicates (including in the layout file)

Comment: @StephenMuecke _layout file scripts..

Comment: You have duplicated `jquery-{version}.js` (and depending on where the one in the layout it, its wiping aout all the other scripts). Strongly recommend you learn and use [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: When i remove .js file not from from layout but from other file, the browser console gives an error @StephenMuecke

Comment: What error (I am not psychic). And again, the original error is because you scripts are not loaded correctly or are loaded in the wrong order.